# Align trailing backslashes vertically

Tags: awk

I have a file that looks like this:

```
abc \
 d      \
 efgh \
i
jklmnop \
q \rst \
uv
wx
y \
z
```

For each group of consecutive lines that have a backslash at the end, I want to arrange those backslashes in a straight vertical line. So the expected output for above sample is:

```
abc   \
 d    \
 efgh \
i
jklmnop \
q \rst  \
uv
wx
y \
z
```

I managed to align **all** backslashes with this program:

```
$ awk '/\\$/ { sub(/\\$/,""); printf "%-20s\\\n",$0; next} 1' file
abc                 \
 d                  \
 efgh               \
i
jklmnop             \
q \rst              \
uv
wx
y                   \
z
```

But I have no idea how to proceed from here, so I'm asking for guidance. I tried searching on SO, but top results were all about removing trailing backslashes.

Details about the actual input:

- Lines may contain any character including backslash and consist of any number of characters, there is no limit.
- There might be multiple blanks and tabs before and after the last backslash.
- There is always at least one blank or tab preceding the last backslash.
- There is no line that consists of only a backslash and zero or more blanks/tabs around it.

P.S. I'm not looking for a Perl solution.

Comment: How large is the file? Looks like it might need a two pass processing. Also how do you determine the line length here? `d` has more spaces, but `efgh` has more characters length. Which one should be taken higher priority here?

Comment: @Inian no larger than 10 megabytes. Last non-blank non-tab character ends the line

Comment: Can you please clarify what's wrong with what you have managed yourself?

Comment: Are the beginning spaces necessary ?

Comment: @Gilles yes. And anubhava I don't want it to look that way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have any tabs before the spaces-then-backslash-then-spaces at the end of each line:

```
$ cat tst.awk
FNR == 1 { prevHasEsc = blockNr = 0 }
hasEsc = match($0,/[[:space:]]*\\[[:space:]]*$/) {
    $0 = substr($0,1,RSTART-1)
    if ( ! prevHasEsc ) {
        ++blockNr
    }
}
{ prevHasEsc = hasEsc }
NR == FNR {
    if ( hasEsc ) {
        lgth[blockNr] = (lgth[blockNr] > length($0) ? lgth[blockNr] : length($0))
    }
    next
}
hasEsc {
    $0 = sprintf("%-*s \\", lgth[blockNr], $0)
}
{ print }
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file file
abc   \
 d    \
 efgh \
i
jklmnop \
q       \
r
```

If you do then I'd suggest running the text through `pr -e -t` first to convert tabs to the corresponding number of blanks.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one attempt using `gnu-awk` with a custom `RS` that breaks input on each substring that ends without a blackslash:

```
awk -v RS='[^\n]*[^\\\\[:space:]][[:blank:]]*(\n|$)' '
{
   sub(/\n$/, "", RT)
}
n = split($0, lines, /[[:blank:]]+\\[[:blank:]]*\n/) {
    lines[n] = RT
    mlen = 0
    # determine max length of a block
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
       if (mlen < length(lines[i]))
          mlen = length(lines[i])
    # print each segment with backslash at the end of max length
    for (i=1; i<n; i++)
       printf "%-" (mlen+1) "s\\\n", lines[i]
}
RT {
    print RT
}' file
```

```
abc   \
 d    \
 efgh \
i
jklmnop \
q \rst  \
uv
wx
y \
z
```

**[Code Demo](https://ideone.com/qPTap5)**

**Details:**

- `-v RS='[^\n]*[^\\\\[:space:]][[:blank:]]*(\n|$)`: Sets record separator using this regex which basically matches a line that doesn't end with a `\`. As a result we'll get all contiguous lines that end with `\` in each record.
- `split($0, lines, /[[:blank:]]+\\[[:blank:]]*\n/`: Splits each record by ending `\` and following line break.
- In the first `for` loop, we loop through each array element and determine longest length of the line i.e. `mlen`
- In the second `for` loop, we just print each line segment using `mlen+1` as length to place trailing `\`
- Finally we print `RT` which is the substring we capture as a result of  `RS=...`